# PageSpeed Insights error Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP from rendertron

Tags: page-speed

I have a single page application and therefore am using [rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) for dynamic rendering as [recommended](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering) by google. Everything appears to be working well. All URL's are available to google from the live test in the search console. However when I test the page speed on PageSpeed Insights and I'm receving the following error: `Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Something went wrong with recording the trace over your page load. Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_FCP)`

Url I'm testing is https://www.voro.com

Rendertron url https://rendertron-voro.herokuapp.com/render/https://www.voro.com

Is this expected behavior? Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I had to look up what "NO_FCP" means.  It stands for "No first contentful paint."  First contentful paint is a web page performance metric that Google is pushing.  When loading a page, it measures when the first text or image is rendered.